# How to raise an issue about a moderator

Tags: support, moderators

How does one go about complaining about a over zealous moderator?

The Moderator's profile just says "you should bring it up on Meta".

Comment: Then why don't you bring it up on meta, instead of asking a question on meta about where to complain?

Comment: @l4mpi, in all fairness, he is not asking where, he is asking how.

Comment: It depends on what the issue are. For example, you can flag questions they've closed for other moderators to look at or even just vote to re-open. For more serious issues contact SE directly using the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of every page.

Comment: Point taken. But still, use common sense (it's super effective!) - simply state any issues you have in a well-formulated post. If it's a smaller issue (e.g. about one specific question/answer), you could also just use a custom flag on the offending post, if you're not paranoid about the offending moderator handling your flag. Nobody's going to ban or harras you because you've got a complaint about a mod, as long as you keep it civil and the issue is not totally unreasonable...

Comment: By the way, I'd suggest you edit the question to something like: "How to raise an issue about a moderator", a negatively phrased question attracts downvotes and these pages are roaming with people who downvote from the hip.

Comment: P.s. it often helps to not go and "complain about a moderator", but ask for feedback on an issue regarding moderation. Generally a far more constructive start (for all parties involved), even if your complaint would be correct.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that one should not complain about a moderator's actions. ;-)

Comment: @l4mpi Could you explain your comment: "why don't you bring it up on meta, instead of asking a question on meta about where to complain". There is the word "meta" twice and it seems that they might be two different things. I really don't understand.

Comment: @Zaph I mean you could have just stated your issue here, instead of asking a secondary question about how to state your issue. Simply asking "A mod did [insert issue here] and I disagree with that because [insert reasons here], what should be done about this?" would have been enough.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Although I have been on SO for a while I have never really been involved in meta nor had an issue I felt needed attention--so I am new here.

Comment: @Zaph Regardless, "Bring it up on meta" doesn't seem particularly complex instructions.  I would honestly expect that you could figure out what that means without needing to ask on meta how to bring something up on meta.

Comment: Some days it feels like the term "overzealous moderator" is redundant :-)

Comment: The question is not mine. I have added a comment, edited the question and made it specific, voted to re-open and flagged the question for moderator attention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, serious answer now that I've had some coffee: just post a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question here describing the issue you've encountered. Include links to relevant posts or comments, and avoid hyperbole.

In most cases, the folks here will analyze the situation and let you know whether there's anything to be concerned about and how best to handle it.

If the matter is of a particularly sensitive nature, you can also contact the team here at Stack Exchange via the link in the footer of every page.

Comment: I have changed the discussion tag to a support tag. Sorry to see your other answer deleted, it was priceless!