# How to complain about an abusive moderator? Maybe leaving the site and erasing all your answers

Tags: feature-request, moderation, moderators, rude-or-abusive

[This moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) had simply deleted [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261998/support-gpos-kerning-table-by-harfbuzz/64865782?noredirect=1#comment114683138_64865782) because it was identical to another answer I gave. Here it is his comments:

*Please don't post duplicate answers, particularly ones that are **little more than links**.
If the questions are the same, pick the best one to answer, answer it fully on site and,
**when you have earned enough reputation, flag the other(s) as duplicates**. If they're not the same, then tailor your answer to the specifics of each question.*

:-))))

This answer is completely ridiculous!!! I cannot comment neither flag any question as duplicate because I don't have 50 reputation. Also, the answer to the question **I had fully answered** in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64825661/how-to-use-and-extract-kerning-pairs-from-from-gpos-table-in-opentype-fonts-to-c). It is obvious that I have to link to this question, right? No, **wrong**! Because my answer is *"just little more than a link"*. You gotta be kidding!!! I gave a whole context with an explanation with **FOUR** more links, and that is just a little more than a link!???. It should actually be just a link to the good answer, right? **Not to him!!!**. You should duplicate a whole answer **DIFFERENTLY** all over again! There is so little sense in this comment that I am willing to delete all my answers and leave this site!!

This is simply grotesque and arbitrary!!! I am 60 years old, I have been programming for 41 years, and I don't need this kind of condescending behavior.

Give me a break!!!

Comment: Your answer contains a *bit* of information other than links, but not very much. To avoid posts getting deleted, describe at least a bit of *how* the links can solve the problem as well. It's not a judgement on you as a programmer, it's just the quality requirements Stack Overflow has.

Comment: _I have been programming for 41 years_. That is irrelevant. I have been programming for 4 and I am 14 years old, so does that mean I should be treated worse?

Comment: This is really just a rant, and it's something we don't need. Link only answers are deleted because the link may go dead at any time and then the answer will be useless.

Comment: Please note that posting here will likely bring scrutiny to all of your posts. You may not want this, please see [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect).

Comment: In what way is this arbitrary? It is standard protocol to delete duplicate answers.

Comment: It's funny how the OP thinks they can just delete all their answers and we have no ability to recover useful ones. High enough rep users can literally just undelete the answers that are useful. This is literally just a rant and empty threat

Comment: Who's condescending here?! 'I have been doing this for long, I know what I'm doing, you don't'. You're right, it definitely gives the feel that the elected moderator is the one unreasonable here. Read your post a second ... Remove the vitriol.... What's left, besides 'I got tripped by a rule, now look at the tantrum I'll throw, you younglings'...

Comment: I feel sad that this has one upvote. :(((

Comment: You are not allowed to delete (or blank out) all your answers (some tried). When posting you have agreed to license it under [Creative Commons BY-SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Seven_regularly_used_licenses). It ought to be clearer that this is the case, but at the bottom of every page is *"user contributions licensed under CC BY-SA.*" (sadly misspelled). The closest is having all your content disassociated from your account.

Answer (score 22):

> This answer is completely ridiculous!!!

While I understand your frustration at receiving this message, and will deal with that shortly, I want to point out that there's nothing "ridiculous" or arbitrary about the way ChrisF handled this situation. What he did is *standard policy* when duplicate answers are posted. Moderators receive automatic flags from the system about this situation, and we always respond in the same way: by deleting the duplicate answers and leaving a comment almost identical to the one ChrisF left for you.

> This is simply grotesque and arbitrary!!! I am 60 years old, I have been programming for 41 years, and I don't need this kind of condescending behavior.

As stated above, it isn't arbitrary. It's literally our standard practice. Your age and experience have nothing to do with it. They aren't even considered by moderators. Stack Overflow doesn't care about who you are or how you identify in the real world. All we care about is contributions to this site. Contributions are evaluated by the site and by moderators on an individual basis, and if the answer you post is a duplicate or otherwise falls short of our standards, then it will be removed. This is not condescension. It's merely reflective of the fact that this is a *moderated* site with quality standards. We feel that this is one of our key differentiators and a large part of what both attracts users to Stack Overflow and keeps them coming back.

> I cannot comment neither flag any question as duplicate because I don't have 50 reputation.
>
> […]
>
> There is so little sense in this comment that I am willing to delete all my answers and leave this site!!

This is a good point. Unfortunately, the merit of your complaint got lost among the "rant"-style character of the rest of your post. And your credibility was completely undermined the minute that you decided to "take your toys and go home" by deleting all of your posts. Leaving aside the immaturity of this response, it is simply not allowed under our license agreement and Terms of Service.

But back to the good point that you raise: this *is* an unfortunate dilemma, and it's an example of the Stack Overflow privilege model being imperfect. On the one hand, we restrict new users from exercising certain privileges for quality control reasons. On the other hand, it sometimes leads into impossible situations, where we're effectively asking you to do something that you cannot do. All I can say is that, on the scale that Stack Overflow operates, moderators simply cannot and do not take the time to assess the privilege levels of individual users and tailor our responses accordingly. We follow standard procedures when dealing with standard infractions like duplicate answers.

One nitpick, though: you *don't* need 50 reputation to flag a question as a duplicate. Only 15 reputation is required to raise a flag. (This created [a bit of a dilemma before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334118), in fact, which led to getting the privilege level lowered to 15.) But that's only a nitpick, because you only had 11 reputation at the time, which means that you didn't have the privileges to flag the question as a duplicate anyway.

Honestly, I do not understand why we limit flagging to users with a certain privilege level. Flags are reviewed by community members or moderators, so there's little harm in letting anyone raise a flag. In this case, you *should* have been able to raise a flag suggesting that the question was a duplicate. I am more and more thinking that even *anonymous* users should be able to raise moderator flags (perhaps with some extra safeguards, like flags from anonymous users not counting towards the automatic threshold for validation of spam/abusive flags).

---

But, let's look at specifics. You posted the following answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261998/support-gpos-kerning-table-by-harfbuzz):

> You should use [Opentype.js](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js) and check the web site https://opentype.js.org. Particularly interesting are [glyph inspector](https://opentype.js.org/glyph-inspector.html) and [font inspector](https://opentype.js.org/font-inspector.html) that you can download the source, run locally and modify. Also check my question: [How to use and extract **kerning pairs** from from GPOS table in Opentype fonts to correctly show glyphs as Path2D in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64825661/how-to-use-and-extract-kerning-pairs-from-from-gpos-table-in-opentype-fonts-to-c?noredirect=1#comment114661345_64825661).

While I'm not a subject-matter expert, I honestly fail to see how this answers the question that was asked. The person is wondering how to get HarfBuzz to support GPOS kerning. You tell them to use Opentype.js. How does that help them to solve their problem?

Maybe it does, but I can't tell. Neither could the moderator who reviewed it. Neither, I'll bet, could the original asker of the question. At best, you're missing some details that spell things out, connecting the gaps for the less knowledgeable among us. At worst, it's just a simple non-answer to the question, which moderators regularly delete. Compounding the problem, it was a repost of several other *nearly identical* answers provided by your account within a short period of time ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64815781), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64864813), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64865461), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64865629), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64865709), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64865831)), and it could be argued that it served little purpose but to promote [your Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64825661/how-to-use-and-extract-kerning-pairs-from-from-gpos-table-in-opentype-fonts-to-c).

> You should duplicate a whole answer DIFFERENTLY all over again!

Well, no. That's not exactly what the comment says. You're arguing against a straw man. I get it, you're upset. But you know how to tailor your answer to the specifics of a particular question. You did it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64858655). It starts out giving the exact same recommendation, to use Opentype.js's glyph inspector and font inspector, but then it gives *specific steps and explanation* on how that applies to solve the problem presented in the question. You didn't do that on [the deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64865782), and ChrisF was saying that you should have.

In fact, in this case, the advice to flag the question as a duplicate was irrelevant. It was just part of our standard boilerplate. That question about HarfBuzz is *not* a duplicate of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64825661), even though you might recommend it be solved in a similar way. That question needs a tailored answer with specific explanation. Your answer wasn't that, which is why it was removed.

Comment: Also, the answer could technically be considered link only.

Comment: @10 No, it can't.

Comment: In my eyes, it's just linking to multiple libraries/products. It's saying "You can use [this. Particulary interesting in [this] is [this2] and [this3]. Also check out my question."

Comment: Suggesting products or libraries that solve the problem doesn't make it a link-only answer. The suggestion of the product or library *is* the answer. In this case, it's not a complete answer because it doesn't connect the dots, showing how the products/libraries solve the problem. But that's different from a link-only answer.

Comment: Thanks for a long post with many nuances; however, I can't see where it answers the question in the title: "How to complain about an abusive moderator?" If it answers that, maybe you could highlight that part more?

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko Basically, there's no need to answer that question, because the correct place to complain about an abusive moderator on Stack Overflow is *right here* on Meta Stack Overflow. They already found the proper place. If that's not sufficient, there is always the [contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) page, which allows escalating an issue with moderators to the Stack Exchange staff (paid employees of the company who runs the site). Also, that question has been answered countless times here on Meta already; see e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255132